# How can you trace what a user read on your blog through the Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, object, types

I have a blog. I like people to login to my website and mark which articles they have read, completely through the Facebook API. Similar in the way how you can currently like (and unlike) a post on Facebook, I like users to be able to read (and unread) a post on my blog.

Now I completed the following steps:

1. Created an app.
2. Users are able to login on my site.
3. I created an action (read) and an object (article).
4. People are able to press the 'read' button and it's being shared on their timeline using:

   FB.api('/me/[MY_NAMESPACE]:read?article=[URL_TO_ARTICLE]');
5. When a user, logs in to my website on a different computer, how am I able to trace which articles it has read?

Or is the only way you can accomplish this by storing this information on your own server using the user.id and the article id? I dislike this thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do a call to the same endpoint to get a list of existing 'read' actions for the current user. Example:

```
FB.api('/me[MY_NAMESPACE]:read', function(response){
  //Do stuff with array of read actions here
});
```